# How to write a virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, emulation, virtual-machine

I would like to learn how to write a small emulator/virtual machine. Does anyone know a good tutorial or a simpler project than qemu/virtualbox?

Thx

Comment: You probably should specify what machine you want to emulate or virtualize: a real processor, JVM bytecode, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Check out my tutorial on how to write your own virtual machine from scratch at http://www.icemanind.com

Its a complete tutorial that will walk you through building a virtual machine and assembler in C#.

Comment: Its not working.... i am facing problems with it... help me

Comment: Looks like good stuff! :)

Answer (score 2):

Anthony Green did a blog series on coming up with an instruction set, porting binutils, gcc, newlib and so on, as well as setting up sim, and qemu to emulate a machine with this new instruction set.  The posts (and patches) are all linked from http://atgreen.github.io/ggx/.  There are a handful of posts that aren't linked from there about various tangential issues.

Comment: From a flag, the link is not working, but this one was brought up instead: http://web.archive.org/web/20100117171845/http://spindazzle.org/ggx/, since I don't like linking to that archive, I'm not editing it into the answer. If anyone has a better link, please edit.